# Default date format setting in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I recently changed my regional setting on Win 10 and this affected how my VBA macros interpret dates and my `Range.Find()`  stopped working correctly.
Below is example of simple macro that is used to return row of a date.

```
Sub a()
Dim dt_start As Date
dt_start = #11/6/2021# ' 11 Jun 2021
Dim rDateColumn As Range
Set rDateColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2").Range("A:A")
rDateColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

w = rDateColumn.Find(What:=Format(dt_start, "dd/mm/yyyy"), _
    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row

End Sub
```

When i try to run it it returns
`Run-time error '91':`.
I also tried this code with
`lookIn:=xlValues`

Even though I set date format to "dd/mm/yyyy" VBA still reads it as "mm/dd/yyyy". See below screenshot.

[image]

I tried to convert the dt_start to string (Format(dt_start, "dd/mm/yyyy") and then back to date DateValue(str_date), however I am getting back I am getting "06/11/2021" which is 6 Novemeber 2021.

Below are my system  regional settings:

[image]

and Excel date settings.

[image: Excel]

Any info much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `What:=Format(dt_start, "dd/mm/yyyy")` searches for a string but if your dates are real numeric dates that does not work, then you need to search for the numeric value. Convert your date into a double and serach for that `What:=CDbl(dt_start)`. Numeric dates are saved in cells as double. Where the number is the amount of days since `1900-01-01` this way you can calculate with dates and format them with number format into any look you want.

Comment: Use `What:=DateSerial(2021,6,11)` to create your search date from year, month, day: this is unambiguous, no matter what your regional settings are. Also, are you sure you don’t want to search `LookIn:=xlValues`?

Comment: This bears repeating because it often causes problems: how Excel stores a cell value internally and what you see on screen are two different things. As @Pᴇʜ says, Excel stores Date information internally as a number: a double where the integer part represents the date and the decimal part represents the time of day). If you want to see the ‘raw’ format of the value in a cell hit Ctrl-Shift-#, and this will remove any formatting. The `.NumberFormat` setting only changes how the data appears, not how it is stored. Do this on cell A4 in your picture to check whether you have a ‘real’ Excel date.

Answer (score 2):

This could help:

```
Sub a()
    'First get the date order (format) from the system.
    Dim myFormatDate As String
    Dim i: i = Application.International(xlDateOrder)
    'xlDateOrder Long
    'Order of date elements:
    '0 = month-day-year,
    '1 = day-month-year,
    '2 = year-month-day
    
    If i = 0 Then
        myFormatDate = "m/d/yyyy" 'NOT mm/dd/yyyy! will give you 00/00/000 not the same in strings.
    ElseIf i = 1 Then
        myFormatDate = "d/m/yyyy"
    ElseIf i = 2 Then
        myFormatDate = "yyyy/m/d"
    End If
    
    Dim dt_start As Date
        'dt_start = #11/6/2021# ' 11 Jun 2021
        'Never trust this... Now you know why!
    
    'Let us built!
    Dim DD: DD = 6
    Dim MM: MM = 11
    Dim YYYY: YYYY = 2021
    Dim w
    dt_start = DateSerial(YYYY, MM, DD)
    'Better to built the var-date using DateSerial
    'Now you have a date and you have the control!
    
    'Dim strDate As String: strDate = Format(dt_start, myFormatDate)
    'the line above is optional, if you want to use instead
    'of: Format(dt_start, myFormatDate)
    'This way: What:=strDate.
    
    Dim rDateColumn As Range
    Set rDateColumn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("2").Range("A:A")
    rDateColumn.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
    w = rDateColumn.Find(What:=Format(dt_start, myFormatDate), _
        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
End Sub
```

[Application.International property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.international#date-and-time)

> Returns information about the current country/region and international settings. Read-only Variant.
>
> **xlDateOrder**: Order of date elements: 0 = month-day-year, 1 = day-month-year, 2 = year-month-day

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, expressions for date and time must follow either the ISO sequence or the "reverse" US format. So:

```vb
Dim dt_start As Date
' dt_start = #11/6/2021# ' 06 Nov 2021
dt_start = #6/11/2021#   ' 11 Jun 2021
```